# How to handle file handling with functions imported from another file in C?

Tags: c, include, file-handling

So here is how my file structure looks like

[image]

Here is text inside my files

**fun.h**

```
void fun()
{
    FILE *filePointer ;
    char i[20],p[20];
    filePointer = fopen("pass", "r") ;
    fscanf(filePointer,"%s %s",i,p);
    printf("%s %s",i,p);    
}
```

.**/pas/pass**

```
inside inside
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "./pas/fun.h"
int main( )
{   
    fun();
}
```

**pass**

```
outside
outside
```

When I am running main.c the output is:

[image]

Which means the code inside fun is searching for pass file inside the file_handling directory where the fun.h has been imported, which is totally understandable.
But it does not solves my problem.

What is want is that no matter where I include the fun.h file it should search for the file inside the pas directory only.

How can I do so?

Comment: Your file structure image should include where the executable is.

Comment: I know that but, is there any way to counter this as I am working on a C library, so the user will include my .h file , now I do not know what will be path of the runnable file of the user.

Comment: Don't but function definitions in .h files.  They should only contain declarations.  The functions should be defined once, in a .c file.  Then the client files *include* the .h file, and you *link* with the object file produced from the .c file.  What you have now will not work properly in any app with multiple source files that use your function.

Comment: @TomKarzes Can you please clarify as bit what do you mean by " link with the object file produced from the .c file."

Comment: In `fun.h`, put `void fun(void);` (you had an incomplete prototype with unspecified arguments - the `(void`) fixes that).  Then in `fun.c`, put the definition of `fun` (also with the missing `(void)` added).  Compile `fun.c` with `cc -c fun.c` to produce `fun.o`.  Similarly, compile `main.c` with `cc -c main.c` to produce `main.o`  Then to produce your linked executable, do `cc -o main main.o fun.o`  That's how multi-file C programs are built.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

~ Using absolute paths.

~ Example:

```c
filePointer = fopen("/home/user/my/path/to/directory/executable", "r");
```

**Solution 2:**

~ Run your program in the main directory (`file_handling`).

~ This should work due to C opening the file:

```c
filePointer = fopen("pass", "r");
```

~ Which will be the one in the main directory.

Comment: Both the above solutions does not solves my problem. I don't know the absolute path in which my present file is getting included.